# The duration of a 75-watt lamp has a stdev of 25 hours. A sample of 35 has average 1014 hours. Find a confidence interval of 98%

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

> It it known that the duration, in hours, of a 75-watt lamp has a
>   standard deviation of 25 hours. A random sample of 35 lamps has an
>   average time of life of 1014 hours.
>
> a) Build a confidence interval of 98% for the average duration of a
>   lamp.
>
> b) What should be the size of the sample so that the amplitude of the
>   interval in a) was reduced to half?

My professor solved a) this way:

[image]
[image]

I don't understand why $\phi(\mathbb{z}_{0.01}) = 0.99$. In the z table I got, approximately, a value that's between -2.33 and -2.32. The average of these points is -2.325. I understand the rest but this part is bugging me. I just don't get what he did.

Comment: In the OP, it reads $\Phi(z_{0.01})=0.99$, not $\phi(z_{0.01}=0.99)$.  And $\Phi(2.32)=0.989830$.

Comment: @MarkViola My bad. Still having trouble finding that in the z table. The values I get are the ones he got, but negative.

Comment: The density function is symmetric.  On which tail (left or right) are you looking?

Comment: @MarkViola Not sure what you mean? I'm looking at the z table and I'm trying to find what are the values for z that give 0.01

Comment: Yes, I understand.  The numbers in the table pertain to a Gaussian (aka, Normal) distribution with zero mean and unit variance.  The Gaussian distribution is symmetric about its mean.

Comment: We have the relation $z_{0.01}=-z_{0.99}$. So you look for the value of $z$ where $p$ is approximately $0.99$  . Then take the negative value to obtain $z_{0.01}$. Btw, the equation $\Phi(z_{0.01})=0.99$ doesn´t seem right. It is right only, if $\phi(z_{0.01})$ is the **pdf**.

Answer (score 1):

The professor seems to be using $z_\alpha$ to represent the **upper** $\alpha$ quantile of the standard normal.

$\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for the standard normal, i.e., $$\Phi(x) = \Pr[Z \le x]$$ for $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$ and $- \infty < x < \infty.$  So when we want to find $x$ such that $\Pr[Z \le x] = 0.99$, or $\Pr[Z \le x] = 0.01$, we are computing an inverse of the CDF.  Due to the symmetry of the standard normal, $$\Pr[Z \le x] = \Pr[Z \ge -x],$$ or equivalently, $$\Phi(x) + \Phi(-x) = 1.$$
So we can go about finding the critical value in multiple ways, but let us be clear on the notation.  I will denote $z_{\alpha}$ to be the number that satisfies $$\Phi(z_{\alpha}) = \alpha = \Pr[Z \le z_{\alpha}].$$  That is to say, $z_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$ quantile of the standard normal.  Similarly, I will denote $z^*_{\alpha}$ to be the number that satisfies $$\Phi(z^*_\alpha) = 1-\alpha = \Pr[Z > z^*_\alpha]$$ to be the **upper** $\alpha$ quantile of the standard normal.  Then $$z^*_\alpha = -z_\alpha = z_{1-\alpha}$$ and we have for $\alpha = 0.01$ $$z_{0.01}^* = z_{0.99} \approx 2.3263478740408411009\ldots$$  If we use a table lookup, we know that $$\Pr[Z \le 2.32] \approx 0.98983, \\ \Pr[Z \le 2.33] \approx 0.990097.$$  We can get a more precise estimate of $z_{0.99}$ by using interpolation instead:  we compute $$\lambda = \frac{0.99 - 0.98983}{0.990097 - 0.98983} = 0.636704,$$ hence our interpolated critical value should be $$z_{0.99} \approx (1 - \lambda)(2.32) + \lambda(2.33) = 2.32637.$$  Comparing this to the exact value shows that we get a more precise estimate to within $10^{-4}$, whereas the crude $2.325$ is actually off by $0.001$.